# Autogenerated MVVM: Validation and INotifyPropertyChanged

Tags: wpf, database, mvvm, entity, auto-generate

I known there are several existing questions about whether to implement INPC on the model, most arguments are about code repetition because of property proxies, which will be not a concern in this case, because the Model and the ViewModel will be autogenerated by a tool, so any code-size arguments is invalid.

**There are any drawbacks in not implementing INotifyPropertyChanged on the Model besides code size?**

Also, the generated Model will be used directly by the programmers but the ViewModel will only be used by other generated code, so the size and complexity of the view model will be hidden, but the Model has to be as simple as possible without losing functionality, in this case **Is better to implement validation and calculated properties on the model or in the view model?**

Consider that the model may be or not database entities.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is too generic a question to be answered. 
"Is better to implement ... ?" : This depends on the application need . Ideally the Model has all the properties and the Viewmodel is just the place where you fill the Model and write the necessary business logic.

Since you are talking about autogeneration, i suppose you have written some util which does this creation. Ideally the validation should be present in both Model and ViewModel. Model side validations are supposed to check any DB/server side validation if present and the ViewModel(VM) is supposed to validate the client for eg: In VM you validate for whether a property is greater than some other property, but in the Model validation you would validate for uniqness or null etc.

Other thing is the calculated properties(I hope this means calculation done in the database and filled in a property), these properties ideally should reside on the ViewModel .

Hope this answers your question.